# Vector field pull back from embedding

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $M$ and $N$ be finite dimensional smooth manifolds.

A smooth map $f: M \to N$ is an embedding if and only if there is an
open neighborhood $U$ of $f(M)$ in $N$ and a smooth mapping 
$r : U \to M$ with $r \circ f = Id_M$.

Does this mean we can pull back a vector-field $X$ on $N$ to 
a vector field on $M$, like we could, if $f$ were a diffeomorphism?

It seems like we can define the vector field $Y$ on $M$ by

$$
Y(m):=r_*(X(f(m)))
$$

Any problems with that? (I'm just wondering because until now I though that we can use only
diffeomorphisms to pull back vector fields, but it seems that this weaker condition is in fact enough. Or what am I overlooking?)

EDIT: An appropriate negative answer has to clarify, why the particular choice of $r$ matters
here. From $r\circ f = id_M$ we get that on $f(M)$ $r'=r$ for any two such maps and hence
$r_{*|f(M)}=r'_{*|f(M)}$. So the only thing that really can be non natural here could be some wired behavior on the boundary between $f(M)$ and $U$.

Comment: This is basic differential geometry, not research-level. I thought that Lev Soukhanov answer would show you where is the problem, but now the ongoing discussion does not belong here. Voting to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At each point $x\in M$ the differential $df_x: T_x M \to T_{f(x)}N$ is a monomorphism. However, if $X$ is a vector field on $N$ the vector $X_{f(x)}$ need not be in the image of $df_x$. Hence to associate a tangent vector to $M$ at $x$, you need a procedure which associates to a vector in the vector space $T_{f(x)}N$ a vector in the subspace $df_x(T_xM)$. To have the correct properties, this vector should coincide with the given vector in $T_{f(x)}N$ when $\dim M = \dim N$. How is that to be accomplished?

For example, of $\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ is the inclusion of the $x$-axis, and $\Bbb R^2$ is given the constant unit vector field with value $\langle 1,-1 \rangle$, how are you going to define a tangent vector at each point of the $x$-axis? The vectors of  the vector field on $\Bbb R^2$ are not tangent to the $x$-axis, so what you wish to have is going to involve making choices (in differential geometry language, this choice is known as a connection).

One way to do this, which is not canonical, is
to choose a splitting $f^*TN \cong TM \oplus \nu$, where $\nu$ is the normal bundle (this amounts to choosing an inner product structure on $TN$, then you can project
$X$ onto $TM$ via the splitting, but this is not canonical (it depends on the inner product).

**Added Later:**

I didn't read the question as carefully as I should have.

The submitter's choice of $r: U \to M$ amounts to 
the choice of a smooth retraction
of a tubular neighborhod of $f(M)$ to $f(M)$.

The space of such choices is contractble, but I doubt that there is
a preferred basepoint in this space of choices.

Furthermore, the vector field you get on $M$ depends crucially on the choice of $r$.

**Example:** in the $\Bbb R^2$ example, let's take $U = \Bbb R^2$ and defined
$r: U \to \Bbb R$ to be (i) the first factor projection, or (ii) the map $(x,y) \mapsto x-y$. If $X$ is the vector field which is $\langle 1,1\rangle$ at every point of $\Bbb R^2$, then $r_*$ applied to $X$ gives the constant unit vector field on the $x$-axis in case (i) and the trivial vector field in case (ii).

(By the way, the retraction induces a splitting $f^*TN \cong TM \oplus \nu$ of the kind
mentioned above.)

Comment: Why has $X_{f(x)}$ to be in the image of $df_x$?

Comment: Not a good style to first downtalk like "by the way ... makes no sense" and then not even say, WHY it makes no sense.

Comment: @Nevermind: Concerning your second comment: you're right. I've changed that. Concerning your first one: I meant without making additional choices. Of course, one wishes the associated vector field on $M$ to have certain properties. I could have stupidly defined the "pullback" to $M$ by taking the trivial vector field, but that is not the correct thing to do in the equi-dimensional case.

Comment: sorry dude but $r_*$ is a map $T_nN \to T_r(n)M$.

Comment: So the question is if different choices of $r$ gives different vector fields on $M$. 

Comment: I would prefer not to be referred to as a "dude." When one writes $r_*$ it usually means a covariant construction.

Comment: Since $r\circ f=id_M$ every choice of $r$ should give the same $r_*$ on $f(m)$. And in the equi-dimensional case this is just the ordinary pullback of a vector field along a diffeomorphism, since embeddings are diffeomorphisms then...

Comment: If $dim(M)=dim(N)$ then $r=f^{-1}$.

Comment: Yes, you're right, the submitter wrote r as a retraction. I didn't read it carefully. The space of such choices is contractible. I retract my rejection to your comment

Comment: Don't need a preferred base-point I think. To be functorial, it should be enough to show that any choice of the retract gives the same vector field on $M$, but as I said at any $f(m)$ the equation $r\circ f=id_M$ gives $r'_*(x)=r_*(x)$ for any two $r'_*,r_*:T_{f(m)}N \to T_mM$.

Comment: But I don't think that's true in general. See the example in my answer.

Comment: Ok. Good point. So this "pullback" depends on the choice of $r$. 

Answer (score 2):

**Edit**

Actually, you are projecting your vector field along $r$. This is noncanonical ($TM$ is embedded in $f^*TN$, but $r$, additionally, gives you a splitting, and it is noncanonical part).

Comment: In other word, your "pull-back" vector field depends on both $f$ and $r$, while to properly define a $f^*X$ you would like it to depend only on $f$.

Comment: Ok it requires both the data of $f$ and $r$ and $r$ is not uniquely defined by $f$. But it is a well defined vector field on $M$ at least. Right?  

Comment: So what you say is,that different choices of $r$ gives different vector fields on $M$? Hmm... Can you explain why?